# Expand grouped objects inside array

Tags: arrays, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm using the follwing to get a list of Instances properties from AWS.

```
Get-EC2Instance | Select @{Name="InstanceType";Expression={$_.RunningInstance.InstanceType.Value}},@{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$_.RunningInstance.InstanceId}}
```

However it is grouping some items (highlighted in bold) like so:

```
InstanceType            InstanceID
------------            ----------
m3.large                i-935aeb54
{m3.large,m3.large}     {i-495eb51d,i-eb1ce266}
m3.large                i-36c93c8b
m3.xlarge               i-0aa5e4c0
m3.xlarge               i-748069f0
{m3.medium,m3.medium}   {i-6305fa77,i-2eb33ffc}
```

I would like to be able to expand these so it is just a normal flat array:

```
InstanceType    InstanceID
------------    ----------
m3.large        i-935aeb54
m3.large        i-495eb51d
m3.large        i-eb1ce266
m3.large        i-36c93c8b
m3.xlarge       i-0aa5e4c0
m3.xlarge       i-748069f0
m3.medium       i-6305fa77
m3.medium       i-2eb33ffc
```

I've tried using piping to `Select-Object -Expand` but I've not managed to get it to work.

Comment: `Get-EC2Instance | Select -Expand RunningInstance | Select @{Name="InstanceType";Expression={$_.InstanceType.Value}},"InstanceID"`

Comment: Spot on! Now I can see how it needs to be used. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your output, it is very likely, that `RunningInstance` property contains collection of running instances, so you need first to expand this property, and only than select the properties you want:

```
Get-EC2Instance |
Select -Expand RunningInstance |
Select @{Name="InstanceType";Expression={$_.InstanceType.Value}}, I‌​nstanceID
```